# How Can I draw multiple figures in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl

Hi I've tryed to draw to diferent figures at same time in WebGL however It only draws the first one. I'm really new with WebGL. I don't know if the problem it's because I don't use the buffers as i have to do it or the shaders.

But I think I use different buffers for each figure becaus i pass in the function "model" and then i do model.Idbuffer... So i think i create a buffer for each one.

Any help it's wellcome thanks.

That's my code.

````
var gl = null;
var program;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
var radi = 0;
var nombre_costats = 100;

var figura = {

  "vertices" : [-0.2, -0.2 , 0.0,
                -0.2, -0.1, 0.0,
                -0.4, -0.1, 0.0,
                -0.4, -0.2, 0.0,
                -0.5, -0.2, 0.0,
                -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                -0.2, 0.0, 0.0,
                -0.2, 0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, 0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.4, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.4, -0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, -0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, -0.1, 0.0,
                0.1, -0.1, 0.0,
                0.1, -0.2, 0.0,],

  "indices" : [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 0]

};

var poligon = {

  "vertices" : [],

  "indices" : []

};

function dibuixar_cercle(x, y, z, radi, nombre_costats, poligon){
  
  var nombre_vertex = nombre_costats + 2;
  poligon.vertices.push(0);
  poligon.vertices.push(0);
  poligon.vertices.push(0);

  for (var i = 1; i<nombre_vertex; i++){
    poligon.vertices.push(x + radi * Math.cos( i * (2 * Math.PI) / nombre_costats));
    poligon.vertices.push(y + radi * Math.sin( i * (2 * Math.PI) / nombre_costats));
    poligon.vertices.push(0);
    if (i>=2){
      poligon.indices.push(0);
      poligon.indices.push(i-1);
      poligon.indices.push(i);
    }
  }

}

function getWebGLContext() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  try {
    return canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  return null;

}

function initShaders() {

  // paso 1
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, document.getElementById('myVertexShader').text);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, document.getElementById('myFragmentShader').text);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  
  // paso 2
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  
  // paso 3
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  gl.useProgram(program);

  program.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "VertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPositionAttribute);

}

function initRendering() {

  gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);

}
  
function initBuffers(model) {

  model.idBufferVertices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(model.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  model.idBufferIndices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(model.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function draw(model) {

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.drawElements(gl.LINE_LOOP, 32, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
}

function draw2(model) {

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLE, nombre_costats*3 , gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
}

function drawScene() {

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  draw(figura);
  draw2(poligon);
}

function initWebGL() {
      
  var costats = 100;
  var radi = 0.1;
  var x_centre = 0;
  var y_centre = 0;
  var z_centre = 0;

  gl = getWebGLContext();

  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL 2.0 no está disponible");
    return;
  }


  initShaders();
  dibuixar_cercle(x_centre, y_centre, z_centre, radi, costats, poligon);
  console.log(figura);
  initBuffers(figura);
  initBuffers(poligon);
  console.log(poligon);
  
  initRendering();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

}

initWebGL();
```
````

Answer (score 0):

In general you should include your shaders for WebGL questions. But in any case the issue is it's `gl.TRIANGLES` not `gl.TRIANGLE`

```js
var gl = null;
var program;

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var z = 0;
var radi = 0;
var nombre_costats = 100;

var figura = {

  "vertices" : [-0.2, -0.2 , 0.0,
                -0.2, -0.1, 0.0,
                -0.4, -0.1, 0.0,
                -0.4, -0.2, 0.0,
                -0.5, -0.2, 0.0,
                -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                -0.2, 0.0, 0.0,
                -0.2, 0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, 0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.4, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.4, -0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, -0.2, 0.0,
                0.3, -0.1, 0.0,
                0.1, -0.1, 0.0,
                0.1, -0.2, 0.0,],

  "indices" : [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 0]

};

var poligon = {

  "vertices" : [],

  "indices" : []

};

function dibuixar_cercle(x, y, z, radi, nombre_costats, poligon){
  
  var nombre_vertex = nombre_costats + 2;
  poligon.vertices.push(0);
  poligon.vertices.push(0);
  poligon.vertices.push(0);

  for (var i = 1; i<nombre_vertex; i++){
    poligon.vertices.push(x + radi * Math.cos( i * (2 * Math.PI) / nombre_costats));
    poligon.vertices.push(y + radi * Math.sin( i * (2 * Math.PI) / nombre_costats));
    poligon.vertices.push(0);
    if (i>=2){
      poligon.indices.push(0);
      poligon.indices.push(i-1);
      poligon.indices.push(i);
    }
  }

}

function getWebGLContext() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

  try {
    return canvas.getContext("webgl2");
  }
  catch(e) {
  }

  return null;

}

function initShaders() {

  // paso 1
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, document.getElementById('myVertexShader').text);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, document.getElementById('myFragmentShader').text);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  
  // paso 2
  program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  
  // paso 3
  gl.linkProgram(program);

  gl.useProgram(program);

  program.vertexPositionAttribute = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "VertexPosition");
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vertexPositionAttribute);

}

function initRendering() {

  gl.clearColor(0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0);

}
  
function initBuffers(model) {

  model.idBufferVertices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(model.vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  model.idBufferIndices = gl.createBuffer ();
  gl.bindBuffer (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.bufferData (gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(model.indices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

}

function draw(model) {

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.drawElements(gl.LINE_LOOP, 32, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
}

function draw2(model) {

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferVertices);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, model.idBufferIndices);
  gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, nombre_costats*3 , gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  
}

function drawScene() {

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  draw(figura);
  draw2(poligon);
}

function initWebGL() {
      
  var costats = 100;
  var radi = 0.1;
  var x_centre = 0;
  var y_centre = 0;
  var z_centre = 0;

  gl = getWebGLContext();

  if (!gl) {
    alert("WebGL 2.0 no está disponible");
    return;
  }


  initShaders();
  dibuixar_cercle(x_centre, y_centre, z_centre, radi, costats, poligon);
  //console.log(figura);
  initBuffers(figura);
  initBuffers(poligon);
  //console.log(poligon);
  
  initRendering();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);

}

initWebGL();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
<script id="myVertexShader" type="whatever">
attribute vec4 VertexPosition;
void main() {
  gl_Position = VertexPosition;
}
</script>
<script id="myFragmentShader" type="whatever">
precision highp float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
}
</script>
```

A few notes:

- There's no reason to use `try`/`catch` around `canvas.getContext`. That function will not throw an exception. It will only return `null` on failure
- it's not common to enable vertex attributes at init time.
- next time try to post a working [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)
- [this script](https://greggman.github.io/webgl-lint/) might help find bugs. It would have found this one.

  > error in drawElements(/*UNKNOWN WebGL ENUM*/ undefined, 300, UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0): argument 0 is undefined

  The reason there are no errors is because `gl.TRIANGLE` does not exist so it ends up passing `undefined` to `gl.drawElements`. `undefined` gets silently converted to `0`. `0` is the same value as `gl.POINTS` which is a valid value. The reason you don't see
  anything is because you have to set `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader to see points.

  This brings up a tip I often follow. Never choose 0 as a valid enum value. It's too easy for something to pass 0 by accident so if 0 is a valid value then the accident will be hard to find. Unfortunately OpenGL choose 0 for `gl.POINTS` and exact issue has wasted the time of 10s of thousands of programmers.
- You might find [these articles](https://webgl2fundamentals.org) useful.